# PHP; Manipulation of Multiple Variables on Single Line?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Basic question really, I know I can do this in some other languages but I dont know PHP that well, hoping someone can help.

So I have the following.

```
$holyToT *=100;
$coldToT *=100;
$fireToT *=100;
$poisonToT *=100;
$lightningToT *=100;
```

And I want to be able to just condense it down to something like:

`$holyToT, $coldToT, $fireToT, $poisonToT, $lightningToT *= 100;`

Does PHP have an internal way of doing something similar?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can cascade normal assignments, but not assignments with an operator.

Comment: You can write a small snippet code code that reduces the number of lines of code but at the cost of complexity (and possibly maintainability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the others, but if you *really* want to have it in one line, you could do something like this:

```
list($holyToT, $coldToT, $fireToT, $poisonToT, $lightningToT) = array_map(function($x) { return $x*100;}, array($holyToT, $coldToT, $fireToT, $poisonToT, $lightningToT));
```

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that. If thats the only other option, I guess i'll stick to the block of code for sets this small.

Answer (score 2):

There is no syntax that allows you to do exactly this in a single statement.

You *could* cook up ways of doing this (by pushing everything inside an array), but the result would be much less clear and performant than a group of assignments.

Something like this comes to mind, but if they catch you doing this don't say you heard it from me:

```
extract(array_map(
    function($i) { return $i * 100; },
    compact('holyToT', 'coldToT', 'fireToT' /*, ... */ )
));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is ni build in functionality. Depending  on the PHP Version you could pass an array and a lambda function to a custom function.

```
function performOnAll(array $a, $fct) { 
    foreach($a as $v) $fct(&$a); 
} 

performOnAll(array($a, $b, ...), function(&$a) { $a *= 100; });
```

That's it basically (not syntax checked).